# Is pasting an excerpt from Wikipedia in a paper without reference plagiarism?

Tags: publications, citations, peer-review

Assume you are reviewing a paper and discover that some general definitions therein have been copied from Wikipedia without mentioning the source. Should it be considered plagiarism or can it be considered legit because Wikipedia is freely available and anonymous?

Surely this behaviour shows poor effort in literature research because if something is on Wikipedia it surely is also in some more authoritative document. However, generic definitions of centuries old concepts should now be copyrightless and Wikipedia is as good as any textbook or giving one in your own words.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what "free" means in this context. I suggest you read the relevant part of Wikipedia's [Terms of Use](https://foundation.wikimedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use/en#7._Licensing_of_Content).

Comment: Even Wikipedia articles have references at the end, so yes they should cite

Comment: When you say "some general definitions" are you talking about well known field-specific definitions? generic definitions of centuries old concepts typically don't need to be referenced if they're the sort of thing that would be in every [field] textbook. If someone rattles off the definition of ,say, the speed of light or something that generic then they , typically if being reasonable, don't need to track down whatever textbook they were taught it from as kids. If it's very generic then that definition might be written everywhere including wiki's.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. Say the definition of eigenvector. There probably exist a hundred slightly different definitions and I could produce many slightly different ones myself. But, in principle, a definition copied word by word is a quotation and, as pointed out, Wikipedia requires citing.

Comment: If the concepts are centuries old then a research paper should not need to define them - they should be understood by the target audience without need for explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Wikipedia is anonymous?*"

Comment: "*Wikipedia is as good as any textbook*" - yeah, so would you not consider it plagiarism to copy an excerpt from a textbook either?

Comment: "if something is on Wikipedia it surely is also on some more authoritative document" -- in fact, it's worth noting that Wikipedia's policies explicitly state that content on Wikipedia *must* exist in some other more authoritative document (see [WP:V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Verifiability)).  If they don't, remove them from Wikipedia.

Comment: @Jules In theory, yes. In practice, there's a lot of references missing.

Comment: These kind of debates remind me to appreciate the fact that mathematicians don't care one bit about copyright or citations more involved than bibliography.

Comment: Is there anything worse than really really bad plagiarism?

Comment: @Bergi I think you misunderstood. I am talking about copying from Wikipedia, not from a textbook (see the title and the body of the question). The last sentence reads: "Wikipedia is as good as any textbook", nothing to do with copying, just a statement about quality.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Copyright for a written work expires some years after the author's death; the length of time under copyright law varies from country to country. Wikipedia and other sites use a variety of licencing models which allow the material to be copied and the conditions that apply to the use of the material.

***But regardless*** of whether something is still copyrighted or not, open source or not, freely available or not, if it is quoted, cited, copied or otherwise repeated in a text, if the source is not cited then ***yes, it is plagiarism***.

When something passes into "common knowledge" then it can be written without having to find a quotable source. But there are also specific situations where something that might normally be considered "common knowledge" needs to be referenced to a source, such as student work where values, definitions, etc., are expected to be researched for accuracy and should also therefore include a reference.

There may also be the case where the value/definition is used in a way that is outside the norm, e.g. a definition that is unusual in the mainstream but is used in a specific way for a specific context, or a value that is based on some work that extends the precision beyond what is considered to be the norm.

The criteria remains, that if someone else wrote it and you copy it then not crediting the original author/source is plagiarism - academic theft.

Comment: if someone rattles off " generic definitions of centuries old concepts" like say the definition of what a cell wall is or the definition of the speed of light or something similarly universally known within the field it's typically considered unreasonable to call it plagiarism.

I just worry that someone will go into automatic bot-like "ah-ha! plagiarism!" mode reading this and some poor students somewhere in the world will get unreasonably accused of plagiarism.

Comment: I agree with Murphy.  It depends on what is being defined, and whether Wikipedia really has a unique or special version of the definition.

Comment: If someone does a copy-paste from _anywhere_ then they should cite the source. If it is a generic definition of a well-known concept in a field then they should not need to copy it from somewhere, but if they don't know it well enough to write it themself and thus they copy it from some source, they need to attribute that source.

Comment: @Mick What if I look it up today, then tomorrow I want to write it down?

Comment: @Mark You should cite your source. Citations aren't just about avoiding committing plagiarism. It is more helpful to readers if you provide complete citations, rather than leaving them to wonder where you're getting the content, and where to go to read more. Bear in mind that 'readers' includes you, the writer.

Comment: @MaxBarraclough I can't imagine a scenario where I'd follow a citation for the first 12 digits of pi, yet I couldn't write them down from memory.

Comment: I would also add that, even if the information has passed into common knowledge, if you copy-paste the text word-for-word, you still need to cite AND QUOTE the text.  You can only state common knowledge without citation if you state it in your own words.

Comment: @Mark What about 16? 256? 2^10? When would you start feeling interested in following up?

Comment: @Mark Numbers are not judged by the same standard as words. One cannot paraphrase a number, and it's understood one will often have to look up even common knowledge numbers since humans aren't very good at remembering them.  A single concept can be expressed in many different ways with words, however.

Comment: @jakebeal That's kind of my point though - there are exceptions to "if someone does a copy-paste from anywhere then they should cite the source."

Comment: @jakebeal, one can absolutely paraphrase a number.  Instead of 10, I might write, for example, 7+3.  These are two different ways of writing the same number.

Comment: @Scott You may be technically correct, but I would strongly disagree with respect to the practical context of  clear written communication.

Comment: @jakebeal, I think that the fact that a single concept can be expressed many different ways with words actually makes particular configurations of them LESS special.  The fact that it is somehow considered a moral imperative to either rearrange or cite your arbitrary words describing an idea that you may or may not have even originated is ridiculous.  Your words describing Pi aren't deserving of any manner of recognition.  It's the CONCEPT of Pi that is special.  That's just my 2c though.  :)

Comment: @Mick If I were to, *from my own understanding*, give the definition of the speed of light there's good odds of it matching, word for word, one of the definitions from a schoolbook I've had over the years. *I can't tell you which one*. No idea. Perhaps it'll end up being a paraphrase mish-mash of a dozen books definitions. perhaps not. But some people don't think when they have a bot like turnitin to auto-check for them, just just see a chain of more than 5 words... and some poor students somewhere in the world will get unreasonably accused of plagiarism.

Comment: @Murphy again, something like the speed of light / definition thereof would now be considered common knowledge and, except in the case of student submissions where part of the exercise may well be to still cite sources, and indeed running text otherwise through Turnitin may raise plagiarism flags. But blind obedience to Turnitin results without checking the actual text is just laziness.

Comment: @Mick Unfortunately the world is full of lazy people.... and some diligent people who see strong statements like "everything must be cited" and thing "the rule's the rule" but lack the normal level of common sense and don't see the implied "but use your common sense and good judgement" bit implicitly appended to almost all rules. Hence my initial comment.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, that is plagiarism. But even beyond that, it's not true that

> Wikipedia is freely available and anonymous

Instead, as you will find on the bottom of every Wikipedia article,

> Text is available under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License; additional terms may apply.

That license specifically requires (as by its short summary)

> **Attribution**—You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work.)

Wikipedia has a *very lenient* understanding of proper attribution – normally, attribution according to the CC licenses is the extreme opposite of *anonymous*! Traditionally, a CC license would require listing *every single contributor* to the document used. The revision history of a Wikipedia article (I'll use ‘Eigenvalues and eigenvectors’ as example) [is public](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors&offset=&limit=500&action=history), and [statistics](https://xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo/en.wikipedia.org/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) suggest that most of the edits are not anonymous (IPs), but at least pseudonymous (users with named accounts) and several of the main authors have account names that suggest those are their real names. We are permitted to give attribution to “the Wikipedia contributors“ (which is at least somewhat anonymous) instead of that list, but an appropriate mention is still required, [such as](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CiteThisPage&page=Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors&id=853269180)

> Wikipedia contributors. Eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. August 3, 2018, 15:11 UTC. Available at: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors&oldid=853269180. Accessed August 8, 2018.

(In addition, that license means that if someone makes use of a text under this license, for example, using some definition on Wikipedia in their paper, they would have to publish their document under a compatible license!)

Comment: You might add that the complete edit history of a Wikipedia article is documented in full, and many authors aren't anonymous (e.g. I wasn't anonymous until my employer objected to my name being associated with my Wikipedia edits).

Comment: I have tried to add it. If you find a better way to phrase it, please edit my aswer.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, it's plagiarism. Being freely available and anonymous doesn't mean you can copy from it liberally, because it's still written by someone other than yourself.

Note that Wikipedia has its own "cite this page" link ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CiteThisPage&page=Enkarterri&id=813739767)), indicating it also thinks it should be cited if you take information from it.

Comment: Makes sense too, couldn't mark it as right solution because someone else was first.

Comment: When you have more than one acceptable answer, you should accept the one you feel is best, not necessarily the first.

Comment: @MarcoStamazza You can change which answer you accept, if you want to. It’s usually a good idea to wait a while before accepting one, in case a better answer comes along.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you are conflating intellectual property rights with plagiarism. The two topics are, for these purposes, unrelated.

Just because a body of work is released to the public and has generous terms of use DOES NOT give you license to claim that work as your own. That is plagiarism.  The definition of plagiarism is claiming someone else's work as your own. Generous licensing does not confer ownership of that property, and a citation is required to attribute that work to its original source.

Comment: That distinction would only be useful if the IP rights to a Wikipedia article were actually permitting use without attribution, but they don't.

Comment: i dont understand what youre saying. you as a user, do not own the article on wikipedia. you as an author, must cite the source if its not an original work. it seems that is a good distinction. i think what youre saying is wikipedia's terms of use are stricter than what is mused above. that certainly doesnt change the fact you dont own the article and have to cite your source.

Comment: You are right; I only wanted to highlight that doing what the OP's article does is *not only* plagiarism, *but also* violating the IP rights, which are not exactly as “freely available and anonymous” as the OP thinks.

Answer (score 0):

My general litmus test is thus:  Is the definition as-is riddled in textbooks everywhere? Therefore I see no reason to, since it is "common knowledge".  If that definition is relatively new and only available in, say, one or two journal articles or some obscure textbook that is the sole authority on a subject (and possibly the wikipedia page), then one references the journal article, if only so that others know where to go learn more about the subject.

Sometimes I discover that I learn a thing from Wikipedia about that definition. But, since Wikipedia disallows original research, that thing is generally reasonably deducible from the definition with a minimum of logic.  And, anyhow, you can't copyright ideas.  Since the thing is not original research, I generally do not cite the idea.  However, since there exist those who would complain about mere phrasing, I reword whatever it is for their sake.

Comment: Seems dangerous. Do you mean to imply you would copy a definition from a text book without attribution, even though it is explicitly copyrighted? Do text book authors have _fewer_ rights somehow? Their publishers would disagree, of course. You  should read the license that Wikipedia puts on all articles. It is quite open, but does require attribution. Sloppy scholarship will only hurt you, actually.

Comment: My point is that the textbook author almost surely did not devise the definition, and did not bother citing anyone.  Therefore, any "copying" that I am guilty of they are as well.  Of course, I'm coming from a math/science sort of perspective.  This may be different in, for instance, philosophy, where half of the debate is over the definitions of various terms.

Comment: In other words, textbook authors have no rights to works that they themselves did not originate.  They also cannot copyright them.

Comment: Fine. It's your reputation, not mine. My degrees are in math, by the way.

Comment: I will note, however, that copyright is for words, etc, not ideas. But citation should go beyond copyright.

Comment: Copyright is for words, but it is not the case that all words are copyrightable.  Indeed, the concept of [merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idea%E2%80%93expression_divide) suggests that things like mathematical definitions are not copyrightable.

Comment: And I agree with you about citation going beyond copyright.  In the sense that, even if I use words close to the definition of a derivative from a textbook from last year, any citation given should not reference the textbook, it should reference Leibniz or Newton.  The precise wording of the definition is absolutely not the thing deserving of citation.

Comment: I take back my statement about textbook authors not citing their authorities.  I picked a cal book off of google search [[1](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/resources/Strang/Edited/Calculus/Calculus.pdf)] and it had no fewer than 16 references to `Leibniz'.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't necessarily plagiarism: The authors may have written both their manuscript and the Wikipedia article.

The authors may have avoided self-plagiarism in their manuscript by writing it first, the self-plagiarism issue on Wikipedia still remains (I'm unsure what Wikipedia's policy is).

Comment: Discussion about copyright, preprints and self-plagiarism [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81515/discussion-on-answer-by-user2768-is-pasting-an-excerpt-from-wikipedia-in-a-paper). If you post any further comments along that line, please make specific suggestions how this answer can be improved. Otherwise take it to chat.